# How is that possible : the same partition mounted twice, and each mount shows a different content?

Tags: mount

Same partition mounted twice, showing a different content on each mountpoint. How is that possible ?

```
# mkdir /mnt/tmp
# mount -t ext4 -o noatime /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/tmp/

# mount | grep sda1
/dev/block/sda1 on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,noatime)
/dev/block/sda1 on /mnt/tmp type ext4 (rw,seclabel,noatime)

# ll /data
drwx------  2 root     root       4096 2021-08-19 18:34 adb
drwxrwxr-x  2 system   system     4096 2021-08-19 18:34 anr
drwxrwx--x  8 system   system     4096 2021-08-21 22:42 app
(...)
drwx--x--x  2 system   system     4096 2021-08-19 18:34 user
drwx--x--x  3 system   system     4096 2021-08-19 18:34 user_de
drwxrwx--x  3 root     root       4096 2021-08-19 18:34 vendor

# ll /mnt/tmp/                                                    
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2021-08-19 18:33 android-8.1-r6
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2021-08-19 18:33 grub
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 1970-01-01 01:00 lost+found
```

The same partition, `/dev/block/sda1`, is mounted twice, and each mountpoint (`/data` and `/mnt/tmp`) shows a different content.

Background : I wanted to modify GRUB's `menu.lst` file, and in android-x86 it appears that file is only available from withing GRUB's debug mode, or from android itself by mounting `/dev/block/sda1`. I did that, and indeed I could then access `menu.lst` (`/mnt/tmp/grub/menu.lst`), but how this works, and why `/dev/block/sda1` shows a different content depending on the mountpoint is beyond me !

[ **EDIT** : answer given by user488112 below ]

It appears `/data` is in fact mounted on `/android-8.1-r6/data`, a sub-directory of `/dev/block/sda1`, and not on the "root" of `dev/block/sda1`. `# mount` is incomplete (it only shows the device block, not the "root" of the mount) :

```
# egrep '/data|/mnt/tmp' /proc/self/mountinfo                         
18 15 8:1 /android-8.1-r6/data /data rw,noatime shared:3 - ext4 /dev/block/sda1 rw,seclabel
237 28 8:1 / /mnt/tmp rw,noatime shared:23 - ext4 /dev/block/sda1 rw,seclabel
```

Comment: maybe you monted the /mnt one after /mnt has already somthing mounted in ? or maybe the /mnt/tmp mounted is not syncronized if so try sync your cache ; and then try again ls

Comment: @francoisP : I added some more tests. /mnt is indeed already mounted, as tmpfs. `# sync` didn't change nothing. I think it's probably android-x86 specific, but how ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how:

```
# cd /tmp
# mkdir foo bar
# mount -B /usr/bin foo
# mount -B /var/log bar
# mount | egrep 'foo|bar'
/dev/sda1 on /tmp/foo type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda1 on /tmp/bar type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

tl;dr; the output of the `mount` command is not reliable on modern versions of Linux. Use `cat /proc/self/mountinfo` instead (the format is documented in `man 5 mountinfo`), which is also showing the "root" of the mount, not just its "device":

```
# egrep 'foo|bar' /proc/self/mountinfo 
380 26 8:1 /usr/bin /tmp/foo rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,errors=remount-ro
457 26 8:1 /var/log /tmp/bar rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. I didn't know that `mount` was unreliable. I updated my original question to add the result of `egrep '/data|/mnt/tmp' /proc/self/mountinfo`. Thanks

Comment: @ChennyStar Or simply use findmnt instead.

Comment: @Roman : yes, `findmnt` is accurate too. Btw `man mount` recommends the us of `findmnt` : `[mount] is maintained for backward compatibility only. For more robust and customizable output use findmnt, especially in your scripts.`. But note that `findmnt` is not always available (specifically it's not available in android-x86, on which I did my tests, even with busybox installed). Whereas `egrep ... /proc/self/mountinfo` seems to work everywhere